# Problem creating a new trigger with a subquery

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to make a trigger that will update a column whenever there is an insert on another table. In my case, whenever I insert a new like in the table `student_likes_post`, I want the table `forum_post` to update its `likes` column accordingly. This is my query:

```
use mydb;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_likes
after INSERT
   ON student_likes_post FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE forum_post 
SET forum_post.likes = (
   select count(*) 
   FROM student_likes_post
    WHERE student_likes_post.post_id = forum_post.id
);
END;

DELIMITER;
```

However, when I run it, it just keeps running forever, nothing is happening. The subquery is working though individually. I tried other triggers on the same table `student_likes_post` that have the same issue. Any idea how I can get this to work? Do you think is a problem with the table itself or with the code?

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking about but as a first thought it seems that you're updating every row in `forum_post` table.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to update *only* the row in `forum_post` for the post that the student liked, not *all* the forum_posts, right?

Your trigger is currently updating all the rows in forum_post, and running the subquery once for each row in forum_post.

Here's another way to write the trigger, that updates only the single respective forum_post row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_likes
after INSERT
   ON student_likes_post FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 DECLARE like_count INT;

 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO like_count
 FROM student_likes_post WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id;

 UPDATE forum_post 
 SET likes = like_count
 WHERE id = NEW.post_id;
END
```

Comment: this looks better for sure, but I still get the same result: the query just running without any message if is right or wrong, just running. My initial update query works as expected for some reason anyway

Comment: If you run the SELECT COUNT(*) query by itself in the MySQL command shell, does it take a long time? Do you have an index on `student_likes_post.post_id` so it doesn't have to scan the entire table every time?

Comment: my project is just in the building phase, the table is new, there are below 10 entries right now. no index in the table but it runs fast anyway. I think it's about the table itself and maybe about the FKs, the query that you provide looks good. It becomes other problem if it's about the table

Comment: Then maybe some other session is holding onto a lock that's blocking your update.